# Criar múltiplos Eventos usando Variáveis para indicar o Evento para Função em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso realizar testes para Eventos `Touch` e `Mouse` em Jquery, e com foco para reduzir o custo de execução no desempenho e tentando simplificar o código para ficar visível, simples e rápido para lidar com escolhas, segue o código:

```js
jQuery(document).on({
  'mousedown': function() {
    alert("Mouse Click");
  },
  'touchstart': function() {
    alert("Touch Click");
  }
}, ".element");
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">Clica Aqui</div>
```

Neste exemplo tudo bem funciona mas eu repetir todo código dentro do `mousedown` para o `touchstart` acho desnecessário. Já vi alguns códigos fazendo assim:

```js
jQuery(document).on({
  'mousedown touchstart': function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
  }
}, ".element");
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">Clica Aqui</div>
```

Funciona mas se eu segurar muito no Evento `Touch` ele mostra o `mousedown`. Então vi alguns códigos para testar que quem clica é um dispositivo com touch ou não:

```js
// Detect Mobile
var mobile = /Windows Phone|Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

var events = {
  startClick: (mobile ? "touchstart" : "mousedown"),
  moveClick: (mobile ? "touchmove" : "mousemove"),
  stopClick: (mobile ? "touchend" : "mouseup")
};

$(document).on(events.startClick, '.element', function(event) {
  console.log(event.type);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">Clica Aqui</div>
```

Esta solução fica ótima e ajuda mas to querendo para múltiplos eventos com verificação do Dispositivo mas quando faço ele não executa. Veja o código:

```js
// Detect Mobile
var mobile = /Windows Phone|Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

var events = {
  startClick: (mobile ? "touchstart" : "mousedown"),
  moveClick: (mobile ? "touchmove" : "mousemove"),
  stopClick: (mobile ? "touchend" : "mouseup")
};

jQuery(document).on({
  'events.startClick': function(event) {
    alert("Clicou: " + event.type);
  },
  'events.stopClick': function(event) {
    alert("Saltou: " + event.type);
  }
}, ".element");
```

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">Clica Aqui</div>
```

Meu problema é este, não quero muito criar várias funções para resolver problema de não repetir o código, simplesmente já no ínicio eu puder indicar o Evento que preciso já ajuda muito. Eu uso o [JsHint](http://jshint.com/) para limpar bem o código e ele da atenção de não usar muito às funções por questão de uso de memória.

Comment: Os eventos de "down" e "up" não são muito problemáticos pois são chamados poucas vezes. Os "move" são mais importantes de optimizar. Podes dar um exemplo dos testes que queres fazer?

Comment: bem a intenção é criar um efeito **Ripple da Google**, agradecer pelo @TobyMosque por me ajudar no [Diminuir o recurso de Elementos no DOM aplicado no Jquery que gera o Ripple](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124697/diminuir-o-recurso-de-elementos-no-dom-aplicado-no-jquery-que-gera-o-ripple) e modifiquei o código mas preciso desses eventos: `mousedown touchstart` e `mouseup touchend` o `mousemove touchmove` funciona mas da conflito quando eu seguro o touch sobre o botão.

Answer (score 0):

Se não quer escrever a mesma função várias vezes, então crie antes:

```
function callback(e) {
    alert(e.type);
    /*[....]*/
}

$(document).on({
    click: callback,
    keydown: callback,
    touch: callback
});
```

Comment: Gostei mas ele não trata a questão de segurar o botão no `touch` porque se eu seguro ele carrega o `mousedown` e com esta solução de verificar o Dispositivo que tem `Touch` ele consegue fixar, fiz um teste no [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltf1t8sq/).